# How to set a new IP address for a clone Linux machine under VMware

Tags: linux, clone

I have cloned a Linux box under VMWare and I would like to use this clone server as a dev server. The clone server is turned off as its IT address will conflict with my production server. I have tried to change its IP address by going to Edit VM setting using VMware workstation but I could not see any option to change IP address. I could only see and generate a new MAC address.
I have also used Vsphere Web client and look for an option to set the IP address but could not see any option.
I guess the only option I have to to shut down my production server, turn on my dev server, change its IP address and then turn on my production server.
Is there any other way to achieve this?
Thanks
Al

Comment: You should be able to temporarily disconnect the cloned system from the network by editing the VM definition and removing the NIC device - then boot it up and change the IP via the console, and then you can re-add the NIC.